# Complex PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
books (id, sku, name, description, date_added)
```

and

```
books_views (id, sku, date_viewed)
```

I am trying to write an optimized query to do the following.

1. To find the most viewed books for the last week
2. To find the most viewed books for the last month

The books_views table has more than 4 million entries. What would be the best way to get the data sorted by views for week and month?

Comment: Where is the number of views stored? What have you tried?

Comment: @jordanm: Presumably, there is a new row added to `books_views` for each view.

Comment: a new_row is added to book_views. I tried creating a table every night books_weekly_views (sku, count) and then using that, but don't think that is efficient.

Comment: Is one of the fields a foreign key?

Answer (score 2):

The query is:

```
SELECT sku, count(*) AS times_viewed
FROM book_views bv
WHERE date_viewed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY times_viewed DESC
```

To get the views for the month, change the interval to 30 days.

To make it fast, you need to make sure that the table is indexed properly. You'll want an index on `date_viewed` for sure. If you're going to want the book names as well, you'll want to index the `sku` columns in both tables. Here's how you'd get the book names as well.

```
SELECT bv.sku, name, count(*) AS times_viewed
FROM book_views bv JOIN books b ON bv.sku = b.sku
WHERE date_viewed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY bv.sku
ORDER BY times_viewed DESC
```

Comment: How can you have an index on `times_viewed`?  It's an alias.

Comment: Works nicely but take about 5.3 seconds. Is that ok?

Comment: That's not surprisingly slow. Chances are you'll want to do nightly rollups and just query the table with those to keep it fast.

Comment: Yes I guess i would just create book_views_monthly, book_views_weekly and use cron to generate those tables every night and just use those. Doing that gets extremely fast.

Comment: Is date_viewed a DATE or DATETIME field?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your books_views table has other fields that you are not showing here you should change your views table to - `books_views (sku, date_viewed, views)` with the PK on sku and date_viewed.

Then modify your insert to be an insert on dup key -

```
INSERT INTO books_views VALUES ('sku', CURRENT_DATE, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + 1;
```

If you want the best performance, assuming more updates than inserts you could do -

```
UPDATE books_views
SET views = views + 1
WHERE sku = 'sku'
AND date_viewed = CURRENT_DATE;
```

then check for the number of affected rows, and then do insert if no rows affected -

```
INSERT INTO books_views VALUES ('sku', CURRENT_DATE, 1);
```